# Should Skip Connections be Fed through Activation?

Tags: neural-networks, conv-neural-network, keras

I'm creating a genetic algorithm to evolve the architecture of Convolutional Neural Networks, which includes skip connections. I have two questions:

1. Where should skip connections start? - after Conv2D or BatchNorm or Dropout?
2. Should these skip connections be patched through an activation prior to being fed into Conv2D?

For example, here is an example of one of my evolved CNN's using skip connections:

[image]

As of current, I simply add the prior connection and the shortcuts and feed them straight into the next Conv2D layer. Some of these Add functions are adding 3 layers, should I pass these through an Activation or leave it as is?